# Styles don't get Tag when imported into QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have a .XML file with lines and fills as well as .svg Images that I want to use as markers. When I Import them into QGIS I want all of the styles to get the tag "IBF". But this doesn't work and I have no idea why. I can Import the styles, they are under the tag "all" and I can manually add each element the IBF tag and then the style appears also under the IBF tag, but why isn't it automatically under the IBF tag?. Is something wrong with my Settings? Here is a Picture of my Settings.

[image]

I'm in the "IBF" Tag when I click on Import and I wrote "IBF" in the "additional Tags" field.

Any ideas on what I missed?